# How to detect where water is coming from on external wall

Tags: repair, water, walls, outdoor, brick

I have recently moved into a new house and when it is raining two patches of water can be seen on either side of the front door:

[image: Damp patch by doorframe]

The pointing has been recently done around the area and I cannot see any holes nor cracks in the brick work.

The only thing I can think is that there is a concrete step on the out side however this have been painted so water would not be absorbed? any suggestions to narrow where this could be coming from would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look higher. Water runs down.  My guess would be over the door.  Why doesn't it shown sooner? Water does stuff like that.

Comment: @Tyson, Thank you I think I may of found it, not sure how the water is getting in but just above the door there is a hole between two bricks. It faces down but would explain why the water is there.

Comment: Post a picture of the front door from the outside, showing from the ground to the roofline.  I doubt it's a downward facing hole.  More likely would be a hairline crack in mortar where door molding meets another surface.  Hard to make suggestions what to look for without pic tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigation and a lot of staring at walls I found the issue

There was a broken seal on a peace of guttering. This mean rain water was dripping out onto the wall and created penetrating damp.

Mow that I have replaced the guttering no more water retention.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a flir camera to find leaks in roofs the water trails show up as cold areas and the thermal image even works to some extent through the wall. In 1 case the water was coming in more than 20' from the wall running down a rafter then down the wall I could not see it with my eyes but the camera made it quite easy to pinpoint. I use the camera for other things like finding bad electrical connections and leaks in ductwork so they can be a handy tool for a home owner there are quite a few models on the market for 200-400$ that work with some smart phones.